# Exception IllegalMonitorStateException for JPA in dbcp2/tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, exception

I have a exception live only while gathering a JPA result:

```
03-Dec-2022 12:29:22.546 SEVERE [SMTP Server Worker (rm-2)] de.e_nexus.server.mail.DefaultSMTPServer$SMTPConnectionWorker$TransportSocket.<init> Created transport socket: a48fc8d5-8cf0-4c9f-88d2-201a47621987 using Socket[addr=/194.50.69.4,port=35600,localport=25]
Exception in thread "Thread-27" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.tryRelease(ReentrantLock.java:175)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.release(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1007)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.unlock(ReentrantLock.java:494)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:436)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:353)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:134)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:753)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.internal.NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.getPhysicalConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:2103)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2040)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2018)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2849)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2831)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2663)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2658)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1414)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1625)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1593)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4243.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:402)
    at jdk.proxy11/jdk.proxy11.$Proxy799.getResultList(Unknown Source)
    at de.e_nexus.web.rm.mail.veto.dnsbl.DNSBlackList.veto(DNSBlackList.java:39)
    at de.e_nexus.web.rm.mail.veto.dnsbl.DNSBlackList.veto(DNSBlackList.java:29)
    at de.e_nexus.utils.VetoCouncil$1.ask(VetoCouncil.java:87)
    at de.e_nexus.utils.VetoCouncil$1Survey.run(VetoCouncil.java:73)
```

This is the class:

```
/*  ___     _
 * | _ \___| |___ __ _ ___ ___  Copyright 2016
 * |   / -_) / -_) _` (_-</ -_) https://www.e-nexus.de./
 * |_|_\___|_\___\__,_/__/\___| by Peter Rader   _
 * |  \/  |__ _ _ _  __ _ __ _ ___ _ __  ___ _ _| |_
 * | |\/| / _` | ' \/ _` / _` / -_) '  \/ -_) ' \  _|
 * |_|  |_\__,_|_||_\__,_\__, \___|_|_|_\___|_||_\__|
 * All rights reserved    |___/
 */
package de.e_nexus.web.rm.mail.veto.dnsbl;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.xbill.DNS.ARecord;
import org.xbill.DNS.Lookup;
import org.xbill.DNS.Record;
import org.xbill.DNS.Type;

import de.e_nexus.server.mail.AllowConnection;
import de.e_nexus.server.mail.VetoConnection;
import de.e_nexus.web.rm.entity.DNSBlacklistService;

@Named
public class DNSBlackList implements VetoConnection {

    @PersistenceContext
    private final EntityManager entityManager = null;
    public static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(DNSBlackList.class.getCanonicalName());

    @Override
    public boolean veto(final AllowConnection plan) {
        List<DNSBlacklistService> blacklistServices = entityManager.createQuery("FROM " + DNSBlacklistService.class.getCanonicalName(), DNSBlacklistService.class)
                .getResultList(); // <-- this is line 39
        String hostName = plan.getIncommingIP().getHostName();
        LOG.finer("Ask for host: " + hostName);
        for (DNSBlacklistService dnsBlacklistService : blacklistServices) {
            try {
                String url = hostName + "." + dnsBlacklistService.getDomainName();
                LOG.fine("Ask url: " + url);
                Lookup lookup = new Lookup(url, Type.ANY);
                Record[] run = lookup.run();
                if (run != null) {
                    for (Record r : run) {
                        if (r instanceof ARecord) {
                            plan.setMessage("Your a spammer said " + dnsBlacklistService.getDomainName() + "!");
                            LOG.warning("Service " + dnsBlacklistService.getDomainName() + " said " + plan.getIncommingIP() + " is spammer!");
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Cant ask DNSBL", e);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

JDK is:

```
/root/amazon-corretto-17.0.4.9.1-linux-x64/bin/java
```

Tomcat is:

```
/usr/local/share/apache-tomcat-8.5.50/
```

Hibernate is:

```
hibernate-core-5.4.28.Final.jar
hibernate-envers-5.4.28.Final.jar
```

DB-Config is (xxx is replaced):

```
<Resource name="jdbc/database" auth="Container" 
 type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
 driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver" url="xxx" 
 defaultAutoCommit="false" username="xxx" password="xxx" 
 maxActive="400" maxTotal="500" maxIdle="5" maxWait="1"></Resource>
```

Comment: What version of tomcat, hibernate, java are you using? Also, does that code run in a transaction?

Comment: The error seems to come from Tomcat's data source. We really need exact versions here, plus possibly your data source configuration (without passwords and real URLs).

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Check the updates.

Comment: @ewramner Check the updates.

Comment: `maxWait - (int) The maximum number of milliseconds that the pool will wait (when there are no available connections) for a connection to be returned before throwing an exception. Default value is 30000 (30 seconds)`. your `maxWait=1` seems like it can cause you problems. According to [docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/jdbc-pool.html) you should set `factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"` on the resource. Also, in the [changelog](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/changelog.html), java 17 support is mentioned under Tomcat 8.5.69. Might help if you upgrade

Comment: Upgrading to the latest Tomcat 8.x sounds like a good plan.